# Concatenate a matrix 5x2 and 5x3

Tags: python, numpy

I have two arrays `A1(5,3)` and `A2(5,2)` and want to create a new array `A(5,5)`. I've try to use `A=np.concatenate((A1,A2))` but it gives me the error

> all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 1, the array at index 0 has size 3 and the array at index 1 has size 2

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To use `np.concatenate` you should specify on which axis the concatenation is happening. In this case, you should use:

```py
A = np.concatenate((A1, A2), axis=1)
```

Other way to solve this issue is to use horizontal stack:

```py
A = np.hstack((A1, A2))
```